# Empty list when converting from set

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a set I've defined into a list so I can use it for indexing.

```
seen = set()
for line in p:
   for word in line.split():
       if word not in seen and not word.isdigit():
           seen.add(word)          
been = list(seen)
```

The set seems to contain items just fine. However the list is always empty when I monitor its value in the variable explorer (and when I later call the index function).

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is the entire code. I'm trying to find the location of words in 'p' in 'o' and chart the number of its occurrences in a single line. It's a huge list of words so manually entering anything is out of the question.

```
p = open("p.txt", 'r')
o = open("o.txt", 'r')
t = open("t.txt", 'w')
lines = p.readlines()
vlines = o.readlines()
seen = set()
for line in p:
   for word in line.split():
       if word not in seen and not word.isdigit():
           seen.add(word)          
been = list(seen)
for i in lines:
        thisline = i.split();
        thisline[:] = [word for word in thisline if not word.isdigit()]
        count = len(thisline)
        j = []
        j.append(count)
        for sword in thisline:
             num = thisline.count(sword)
             #index=0
             #for m in vlines:
                 #if word is not m:
                 #index+=1
            ix = been.index(sword)
            j.append(' ' + str(ix) + ':' + str(num))
        j.append('\n')
for item in j:
  t.write("%s" % item)
```

Output should be in the format '(total number of items in line) (index):(no. of occurrences)'.
I think I'm pretty close but this part is bugging me.

Comment: `been` should be a list of the items in `seen` without any problems.  Do you have an indentation issue perhaps?

Comment: Also, it is computationally very inexpensive to just try adding to the set even if it is already present, so you *can* remove the `word not in seen and` part of your `if`, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working just fine.

```
>>> p = '''
the 123 dogs
chased 567 cats
through 89 streets'''.splitlines()
>>> seen = set()
>>> for line in p:
       for word in line.split():
           if word not in seen and not word.isdigit():
               seen.add(word)


>>> been = list(seen)
>>> 
>>> seen
set(['streets', 'chased', 'cats', 'through', 'the', 'dogs'])
>>> been
['streets', 'chased', 'cats', 'through', 'the', 'dogs']
```

Comment: Does that count as an answer?! :P

Comment: @user2951046 The list doesn't even exist until the last line, ``been = list(set)``.  At that moment, it is created and is non-empty.  If you want to trace the code, look at the *set* not the list.  You can see the set *seen* grow between iterations of the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a reason why you want to read line by line you can simply replace this:

```
seen = set()
for line in p:
   for word in line.split():
       if word not in seen and not word.isdigit():
           seen.add(word)          
been = list(seen)
```

with:

```
been = list(set([w for w in open('p.txt', 'r').read().split() if not w.isdigit()]))
```